# How to remove margin between two grids in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to remove / collapse the margin & padding between the two grid columns in bootstrap. Here is my code and screenshot.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Short Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="txtShortName" class="form-control " type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Descripition</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="txtDescripition" class="form-control" type="text"  />
        </div>     
    </div>        
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Find following code in your **Bootstrap** CSS and change `padding` according to your need.

```
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Above code will be under .col-xx-y where xx is md,sm,lg etc and y is 1,2,3 and so on ..

**Note** : If you change in that bootstrap CSS , it will take effect on your every HTML file.So I would suggest you to make custom CSS to **override** it.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap the pre-defined class like `col-md-3` and `col-md-8`take the default `padding-left:15px;` and `padding-right:15px;` so you can just give one extra class beside `form-group` and target those two col classes to your css in which you wrote the custom css and make the padding to 0 or we can say just overwrite it.

please follow below edited code.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group Myform">
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Short Name</label>
         <div class="col-md-8">
           <input id="txtShortName" class="form-control " type="text" />
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group Myform">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Descripition</label>
         <div class="col-md-8">
           <input id="txtDescripition" class="form-control" type="text"  />
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

please add below css to your custom css file

```
.Myform .col-md-3, .Myform .col-md-8 {padding-left:0;padding-right:0;}
```

if it doesn't overwrite the bootstrap css then you can simply add suffix to the css properties like

```
.Myform .col-md-3, .Myform .col-md-8 {padding-left:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;}
```